# trying to build org chart using OrgChatJs in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, chartjs

I am trying to build a Org Chart using OrgChatJS (https://balkan.app/OrgChartJS/Docs/GettingStarted) in LWC .  It will look like this

[image]

But in Salesforce , its coming a blank page. Anything i am missing. Below is my code

JS -

```
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';
import { loadScript, loadStyle } from 'lightning/platformResourceLoader';
import orgChart from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/orgchart';

export default class Dorgchart extends LightningElement {
    error;
    chart;
    initialized = false;

    renderedCallback() {
        if (this.initialized) return;
        this.initialized = true;

        Promise.all([
            loadScript(this, orgChart),
        ])
            .then(() => {
                console.log('script loaded')
                this.intialized3();
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                this.error = error;
            });
    }

    intialized3() {
        let canvas = this.template.querySelector(".orgchart");
        let context = canvas;
        this.chart = new OrgChart(context, {
            mouseScrool: OrgChart.action.none, nodeBinding: {
                field_0: "name"
            },
            nodes: [
                { id: 1, name: "Amber McKenzie" },
                { id: 2, pid: 1, name: "Ava Field" },
                { id: 3, pid: 1, name: "Peter Stevens" }
            ]

        });
        console.log(this.chart)

    }
}
```

HTML -

```
<template>
    <div class='slds-box slds-theme_default custom-background'>
        <div class="orgchart" width="800" height="450" lwc:dom="manual"></div>
    </div>
</template>
```

Comment: 1. add debugs to initializeD3 to make sure it's working
2. is your static resource a single JS file or an archive?

Comment: Static resource singls JS file. Code is reaching to initializeD3 ..

Comment: Sorry, thought you were loading d3. Orgchart might not be supported in lwc.

Comment: Does D3 has org chart plugin ?

Comment: Does D3 has org chart plugin ? or any other example where LWC supports org chart

Comment: @CasparHarmer I think it shouldn't really matter, if script loads I think it should work

Comment: Yes.. I used it in VF page.. it works fine.. I am struggling in LWC..

Comment: @hellraizer did you get any solution for this ?

Comment: Hi Shri .. in Aura used 39.0 version api .. then it worked

Answer (score 0):

Add this line to the orgchart.js at EOF:

```javascript
window.OrgChart = OrgChart;
```

Try to add above line in orgchart js file at the end and then try to use it
it is also suggested in salesforce doc for balkan
https://balkan.app/OrgChartJS/Docs/Salesforce

Comment: At the time of writing, I don't believe this works anymore.